# ElasticSearch - score match query by edit distance

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm diving in ElasticSearch, and my supertask is to provide fuzzy search for exact single term with ranking by edit distance between searched term and found term, ignoring tf/idf and other scoring models, basically like this (it hasn't to be exactly like this, e.g. it's not necessary to treat transposition as single edit):

```
search: mark

output:
  - mark: 1.0
  - marx: 0.5
  - marks: 0.5
  - marker: 0.25
  ...
```

Is this possible with ElasticSearch and without tricky scoring scripts? I've tried to do it out-of-the-box, but i've suddenly got `mark-a` ranked higher than exact match `mark` (and my analyzer **did not** split `mark-a` to tokens `mark` and `a`).

Comment: necrocomment: most probably (i'm not sure, though) this was effect of [query-then-fetch mode](https://www.elastic.co/blog/understanding-query-then-fetch-vs-dfs-query-then-fetch)